# Where to run 4" exhaust fan duct?

Tags: bathroom, vent, joists, fans, exhaust

I'm installing an exhaust fan in my bathroom. I plan to install it somewhere left of the octagon box that you see in the picture, However, there's a 5 3/4" joist right there. I'm not sure if I can drill a 4 1/8' inch hole through there. Is that a smart idea? Is it a rim joist? There is a floor above me. I was thinking I could drop the duct down into that triangle in the left corner. Then cover it somehow after it gets sheetrocked. What do you think?[image]

Comment: Is the left wall also exterior?

Comment: I would not drill that big of a hole through the rim joist- even if it is only a ceiling joist and not the upper floor joist. Why not drop the ceiling to create a soffit which is enough to fit your fan and the ducting and not mess with the existing structure ?

Answer (score 0):

First, verify the purpose of that lumber.

Second, if you do cut a hole in it I would squash the duct slightly.  This will preserve some of the beam.  It will impact the volume of the duct and the airflow, but not enough to matter unless you make a pancake out of it.

Third, I'd reinforce the beam with something like 4' of angle-iron.

or D) none of the above, install the fan in the exterior wall.  :)

Mind you this is my "off the cuff" guesstimate.  More data is needed for a better answer.

Comment: If more data is needed, then you should not answer it.  This site is not a discussion forum.  Please our the help.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the best I can do, Rohit.  If you want to engage the asker to find out relation to the property, the nature & purpose of the exposed beam, regulating municipality & applicable building codes, etc I will be happy to vote for your superior answer.